# IE 6 Images are not shown

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, image

I have a dynamic div created which contains text + images. These images are shown well in all browsers, except IE6. I need to do a right click show pictures, then they come. Looks like its a bug with IE.

Comment: Have you used fiddler2 to see if the image request is made? Also it would help if you could include either some code, or better a demo/ url of the issue to help people debug the issue.

Comment: Are you loading the images in from the local file system, or are you pulling them in from a remote server?

Comment: @Robert The files are pulled from server

Comment: @redsquare Try demo link at www.vidteq.com and click on Email Link

Comment: @redshatquare It seems that request for image is made in some cases and at other times, show picture options sends a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a lot of DHTML in IE6 and have not come across this problem.  However, given the strange behavior of IE6 in general, nothing surprises me.  In cases such as this, I suggest a bit of "riffing".  For instance, if you append an *img* tag to an element while the parent element's *display* property is *none*, IE6 may lazily decide not to load it.  Try setting *display* to *block* prior to appending the *img* element.  Or, if the *img* tag already exists, try waiting until after the container is shown before setting the *src* attribute of the tag.  Lastly, if you're updating the HTML of the div by changing the *innerHTML* property, try using DOM methods like *addChild* instead.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know IE6 doesn't correctly handle PNG pictures. Are you talking about png? jpg?

Comment: IE6 will show them, it just cant handle the alpha channel transparency so they look odd hence the multitude of pngfix javascript libs that are out there

Comment: They are jpeg images. PNG has problems with transparency